# how to deploy different jobs on different Virtual Machine(slaves) having same environment in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, master-slave

In jenkins I am using master slave architecture to dynamically deploy a slave machine and perform some operations on it. I want to deploy different jobs on different Virtual Machine(slaves) having same environment( i.e slave having same label). What is possible solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

use different labels so you can choose which job should run on which label.

Comment: actually I want to deploy set of jobs on same environment. But each job should be on separate VM. Thus if I want environment with windows 10 on it, then I want to run job1 on VM1 with win 10 on it and again Job2 on vm2 with win 10 on it. So I must use same label for all.

Comment: You can use the parallel keyword in all your jobs. Inside the parallel stage you can have assign each stage to a individual label/agent. So you can run multiple job in parallel and each job spreads acrosse different machines also in parallel. Please check out this tutorial: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/